How to solve water pooling in crawl space?
Recently was told that we are having a lot of water pool underneath our house. A friend of a friend came too look and told us that we need a crawl space system drain on 3 sides of the house and a sump pump. I have no idea how severe getting this fixed is but the quote was a lot higher than anticipated. Is this a severe problem? Why did it pass home inspection if it’s a huge problem, what are ways to get it fixed?

An inspection would likely only have caught this if there had been some significant amount of rainfall shortly before the inspection took place.

You need to do two things:

Stop the infiltration of water that is causing the pooling.
Provide a way for any water that does get in to drain or be drained away.

So the first thing is to find where the water is coming from and fix that issue.  The most common reason is downspout water not draining away from the foundation or a grade that slopes toward the house instead of away.  Either fix the issue yourself or get a professional to do it but this is an important problem.  Water pooling in the crawlspace will cause expensive problems down the road.
Installing a gravity drain (if possible) or a sump pump will also help in case some water does get it.  But a sump pump is not the best overall solution for large amount of water.  Generally the water coming in will overwhelm the pump and you will have standing water for a while, perhaps a long while, as the pump catches up.
So PREVENTION is your best first step.
